# How does glmnet handle NA values?

Tags: r, na, glmnet, lasso-regression

How does `glmnet` in the R package 'glmnet' handle NA values?

Or can it not tolerate NA values?

Comment: the data needs to be complete

Answer (score 14, accepted):

glmnet doesn't handle missing values. Either you have to keep only those records that are complete. e.g. with complete.cases() or do some imputation on your missing values with packages like mice, mi, amelia, etc etc.

You could have a look at this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104194/how-to-handle-with-missing-values-in-order-to-prepare-data-for-feature-selection) which discusses handling missing values and glmnet.